# Regex to replace special characters with specific sign

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to use Regex to change my URL from this:

```
http://localhost:51577/Item/92MM+BLACK+CASE+FAN+W%2f+3+PIN+CONNECTOR+-+Cool+%26+Quiet/222069843383
```

Into a URL that would look like this:

```
http://localhost:51577/Item/92MM-BLACK-CASE-FAN-W-2f-3-PIN-CONNECTOR-Cool-26-Quiet/222069843383
```

Any `%`, `+` or `+-+` sign would be replaced with `-` sign using regex. I think regex is the best solution for this, but I'm not so familiar with writing regex expressions... Can someone help me out with this?

Edit: Guys I have an even better idea... I have the Title name in controller in following format:

```
92MM BLACK CASE FAN W/ 3 PIN CONNECTOR - Cool & Quiet
```

How could I write an regex to replace white spaces and remove any extra white space (if there are any) in the string array...

Edit 2: Basically replacing any special character with a `-` sign... Any ideas?

Comment: `I think regex is the best solution` Have you tried `String.Replace` ?

Comment: You _do_ realise that `%2f` is the `/` and `%26` is the `&` in your original title, so why do you want to replace them?

Comment: You realize those two URIs have different meanings and characters like `/` and `&` are URL metacharacters? Your first example URL-encodes the “Title name” string and your second does not. This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/); please explain why you want to change your URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Regex.Replace(YOUR_STRING, "[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", "-");
```

Try that

Comment: small adjustment for the exprected result: `Regex.Replace(txt, "[^0-9a-zA-Z:/]+", "-")`;

Comment: Thank you! That worked like a charm :)